# What are the requirements to teach in an Austrian public school?

Tags: working, austria

Are there any requirements that one must have to teach in a Viennese (Austria) public school?

Such as:

1. Do I need a college degree?
2. Do I need some kind of credentials?

I'm an American, For what it's worth.

Comment: Unless it's a bilingual School, speaking fluent German is probably a prerequisite. Do you?

Comment: Assuming you are indeed completely fluent in German, you should be able to research through Google.at the necessary requirements. While there is almost certainly a basic set of requirements for all of Austria, each school will have its own needs and desires. I just did a brief look and there is wide breadth of possibilities. It depends on what you want to teach, where you want to live, and what those schools expect.

Comment: What kind of school? (Or even better: What school exactly?). And what subject?